# Determine share connection based on username

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I'm using a piece of hardware that is limited to the share it will connect to (annoyingly). At the moment there is absolutely nothing that I can do to get around that as the hardware isn't developed by myself. In other words, it'll only connect to a share with the name `theshare`.

What I was wondering was whether it is possible for the folder behind the share a user is connected to is based on their username? So, the user will always be connecting to `\\server\theshare`. What I want, is for the contents of `theshare` to be different based on the user that is connecting.

Is that at all possible? I'm running Samba 4.3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely yes.

```
[theshare]
comment = Mapped as %u
path = /home/%u
```

This example will map the share according to the username (`%u`) that has authenticated.